# Finding total active hours by calculating difference between TimeDate records

Tags: mysql

I have a table to register users logs every one minute and other activities using **DateTime** for each **user_id**

This is a sample data of my table

```
id   |   user_id   |     log_datetime
------------------------------------------
1    |      1      |   2016-09-25 13:01:08 
2    |      1      |   2016-09-25 13:04:08 
3    |      1      |   2016-09-25 13:07:08 
4    |      1      |   2016-09-25 13:10:08 
5    |      2      |   2016-09-25 13:11:08 
6    |      1      |   2016-09-25 13:13:08 
7    |      2      |   2016-09-25 13:13:09 
8    |      2      |   2016-09-25 13:14:10
```

I would like to calculate the **total active time** on the system

---

**UPDATE: Expected Output**

For Example `user_id` 1 his total available time should be **00:12:00**

Since his hours and seconds are same so I'll just subtract last log from previous then previous from next previous and so on then I'll sum all subtracted values
this a simple for

Simply I want to loop through the data from last record to first record with in my range

this is a simple formula I hope that make my question clear

SUM((T< n > - T< n-1 >) + (T< n-1 > - T< n-2 >) ... + (T< n-x > - T< n-first >))

Since `user_id` 1 his **hours** and **seconds** are  the same then I'll calculate the **minutes** only.

(13-10)+(10-7)+(7-4)+(4-1) = 12

```
user_id   |       total_hours
---------------------------------
   1      |        00:12:00 
   2      |        00:03:02
```

---

I did this code

```
SET @start_date = '2016-09-25';
SET @start_time = '13:00:00';

SET @end_date = '2016-09-25';
SET @end_time = '13:15:00';

SELECT 
`ul1`.`user_id`, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`dl1`.`log_datetime`))) AS total_hours 
FROM 
`users_logs` AS `ul1`
JOIN `users_logs` AS `ul2` 
    ON `ul1`.`id` = `ul2`.`id`

WHERE  
`ul1`.`log_datetime` >= CONCAT(@start_date, ' ', @start_time)
AND
`ul2`.`log_datetime` <= CONCAT(@end_date, ' ', @end_time)


GROUP BY `ul1`.`user_id`
```

But this code **Sum all Time** not getting the difference. This is the output of the code

```
user_id   |       total_hours
---------------------------------
   1      |        65:35:40 
   2      |        39:38:25
```

How can I calculate the **Sum of all difference datetime**, then I want to display his active hours every **12 hours** **(00:00:00 - 11:59:59)** and **(12:00:00 - 23:59:59)**  with in selected **DateTime Period** at the beginning of the code

So the output would look like this (just an dummy example not from given data)

```
user_id   |  total_hours  |   00_12_am  |   12_00_pm  |  
-------------------------------------------------------
   1      |   10:10:40    |   02:05:20  |   08:05:20  |
   2      |   04:10:20    |   01:05:10  |   03:05:30  |
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to get the `TIME_TO_SEC(@start_time)` of your start time and subtract that from your `TIME_TO_SEC(dl1.log_datetime)`  to give you the seconds from 13:00:00. TIME_TO_SEC always starts from 00:00:00 which is why your values are so inflated.

Comment: What does an entry in the table represent? A login time? A logout time? A second during which the user was using the system? It looks weird to see a table of timestamps without any context. One woud rather expect a table of time spans, i.e. a start time and an end time. Or at least records with a time and an action ('login' / 'logout').

Comment: @R.Chappell Acctually because I have over 1000 record for all user I was testing the code for specific time so I can calculate manually to see if my code is return correct output. I usually set `@start_time` at 00:00:00, and `@end_time` at 23:59:59

Comment: Ok, so you want the time difference between what exactly? The first log and the end log for that time period?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it's an app for the company employee there is an option **available** if they set it **On** then they'll receive a messages and notification from the system. if **Off** then they'll  not receive anything. I want to calculate how long they were available (there are other columns that I didn't provide because my main concern is to get the **difference datetime** )

Comment: So you know when they logged in (because then a record gets generated), but you don't know when they logged off (because then no record gets generated)? How then do you know how long they were logged in?

Comment: @R.Chappell for `log_datetime` of each `user_id`. Each user has multiple log almost every minutes so if he was available **5 minutes** and there were **5  records** of `log_datetime` I should **subtract** last record from the previous, then previous from next previous and so on then calculate the **Sum** of all the subtracted values to get total **00:05:00**

Comment: @R.Chappell is right, you are missing context information. Without any context, instead of the complicated code you have, you could simply determine the minimum and maximum log_datetime per user id and subtract those from each other and you have the active timespan.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You are right I know there is something wrong with schema that they don't trigger when the user set he was **not available** I told them about this and they are going to update the schema. currently because the app log every **minute (almost)** for  the old data we'll check if there are lag in log for more than **3 minutes** then we'll assume that the user was **not available** from **(last log + 3 minutes)** untill the next `log_datetime` after 3 minutes will be his next available time

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Currently all these `log_datetime` are for his **available** time only

Comment: You new calculation is simply last minute minus first minute => 13 -1 = 12 minutes. But why is there no entry for minutes 2 and 3 for instance? This indicates that the user wasn't active. (With your method a user is never inactive between their first entry till their last, which can be years.)

Comment: Just in case you don't understand what I am saying: `(13-10)+(10-7)+(7-4)+(4-1)` = `13 + (-10+10) + (-7+7) + (-4+4) - 1` = `13 - 1`. So the whole looping through the data makes no sense, because all records between first and last get both added and subtracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you log every minute and if a user is available there is a log entry.

Then count the logs per user, so you have the number of total minutes.

```
select user_id, count(*) as total_minutes
from user_logs
group by user_id;
```

If you want them displayed as time use sec_to_time:

```
select user_id, sec_to_time(count(*) * 60) as total_hours
from user_logs
group by user_id;
```

As to conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  user_id, 
  count(*) as total_minutes,
  count(case when hour(log_datetime) < 12 then 1 end) as total_minutes_am,
  count(case when hour(log_datetime) >= 12 then 1 end) as total_minutes_pm
from user_logs
group by user_id;
```

**UPDATE:** In order to count each minute just once count distinct minutes, i.e. `DATE_FORMAT(log_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')`. This can be done with `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` or with a subquery getting distinct values.

The complete query:

```
select 
  user_id, 
  count(*) as total_minutes,
  count(case when log_hour < 12 then 1 end) as total_minutes_am,
  count(case when log_hour >= 12 then 1 end) as total_minutes_pm
from 
(
  select distinct 
    user_id, 
    date_format(log_datetime, '%y-%m-%d %h:%i') as log_moment,
    hour(log_datetime) as log_hour
  from.user_logs
) log
group by user_id;
```

Comment: there are other activities such as reply to a message or change ticket status or anything that would be stored on his logs within the same minute 

Please check my update on the question to understand the expected output of the given data

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer. Hope it works for you. I still cling to counting minutes. See my comment on your altered request above.

Comment: I've checked your code logic is counting how many records for each user and count it as 1 minute.  but the fact that the user may be a delay of few seconds or the user may do something within the same minute so in this case in your code you are counting this record as one minute which is wrong.

Comment: I think it should loop through each `user_id` record and usimg `SUM()`  of all values in `TIMEDIFF(last_datetime, current_datetime)` until it reach the first record

Comment: Well, if it is supposed that there is at least one record per minute a user is active, you'd have to count the distinct minutes. Did you even read my comment on your loop solution under your request? You are right that there may be minutes missing, but approximate data only gets you approximate results. Of course one could define an allowed gap, say 2 missing minutes between two records that would still count as online, whereas a gap of three minute would then count as offline. But this is quite hard to achieve, especially with MySQL lacking analytic functions.

Comment: Thank you Thorsten Kettner  for your suggestion. After looking at all the logs that we have I found that approximately around 1 minute (more or less) are the gap between each log rarely I find 2 minutes. I was testing looping and detecting on my localhost and it took time to run the query so I end up using your query. Thank you